# Microsoft Teams. Cannot receive channels information

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

As a global administrator I would like to fetch information about all teams, channels and it's messages from Microsoft Teams using Microsoft Graph API. As long as I make calls to the teams which I am member of everything is fine. However, when I am trying to access channel data from the group/team which I am not a member of I am getting:

> "Access Denied" "Failed to execute Skype backend request
>   GetThreadRequest"

I have added Group.ReadWrite.All and Group.Read.All premissions to my native application for both Microsoft Graph application and Microsoft Graph delegate premissions. Is there something what I am missing of?

Thaks for you help.

Comment: I have tried this. First, I grant the `Group.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All` permission, and I have a `Doc_V1.0` team channels and the global administrator is not in this team/group. Second, I tried the `/teams/{id}/channels` API in the MS Graph Explorer with the global administrator. I got the `Doc_V1.0` team channel. So could you please provide the simple code or the request screenshot in the MS Graph Explorer?

Comment: This is By Design. Graph explorer is special and it will work via Graph explorer. The API's are not yet enabled for tenant administrator access.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your response.